# found this flying ant like insect in pune, help me identify it?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, taxonomy

[image: It looks like species of ant but not sure]

Is it species of wasp or ant or fly? I found it in Pune/India. I need its common name at least.

Here is another photo I managed to take...Found at same place as previous one.

[image]

Comment: It looks like a a species of a genus [Baccha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baccha_(hoverfly)) (which are [hoverflies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoverfly)). Maybe [Baccha elongata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baccha_elongata).

Comment: Can you please add more information. What approximate size is it? Where did you see it (country, region, type of ecosystem)? What did you see of its behaviour? Typically, is it able to hover?

Comment: @Remi.b Comparing the eyes of Baccha elongata from the wikipedia link to the picture given, the species in question does not look like a hoover fly.

Comment: I do believe this to be a fly, but it is probably not a hoverfly (Syrphidae); the antennae appear to have more than three segments.  If you see it again (or already have other photos from different angles), adding them would be a help.

Comment: It was found in Pune, India. It was not able to hover, but it was moving swiftly. I think it is a fly but could not find any matching known species from my region. It was about 1.5cm long, found it in garden. I have only one picture of it, i'll see if i can find it again.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a syrphid. It is a fly in the family Megamerinidae, genus Texara. Very little is known about their biology, and they are rather uncommon.

Comment: You might very well be right. Could you add a source or a picture for verification?

Comment: This isn't a Megamerinid fly; the same objection I made to "hoverfly" (see my note of February 25th) apply here, and would apply to any Dipteran family belonging to the infraorder Muscomorpha.

Comment: Sorry I didn't add a verification - I only just noticed the request for that. In any case, yes, it is definitely Texara (a megamerinid fly) - see this https://lkcnhm.nus.edu.sg/app/uploads/2017/04/sbr2016-148.pdf, as well as google searching. I've collected a fair number of specimens of this group of flies in Asia, and even photographed it myself. [Edit: regarding the antenna - the elongated part is the arista, not the full antenna]